# Impliziert "leugnen" die Behauptung des Gegenteils einer erwiesenen Tatsache?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Die Frage steckt eigentlich schon im Titel. Aber ich möchte auch ein Beispiel geben:

1. Atheist: der Gottesleugner
2. Atheist: der Gottesverneiner

Die erste Definition stammt so aus dem Brockhaus. Sie findet sich aber auch in diversen anderen Lexika in ähnlicher Form. Die zweite Variante habe ich einfach einmal im Rahmen dieser Frage *erfunden* um den empfundenen Unterschied herauszuarbeiten.

Beim Wort *leugnen* schwingt für mich auch immer mit: die Wahrheit leugnen. Und also: das Gegenteil einer erwiesenen Tatsache zu behaupten.

Ist dem so, oder trügt mich mein Sprachgefühl?

Comment: gute Frage... ich halte "Gottesleugner" für ein sehr unglücklich gewähltes Wort,d a es für mich in der Tat impliziert, dass Gott existiert... eine Kleinigkeit: Reicht im vorletzten Satz nicht nur "Tatsache"? Ich denke, das "erwiesen" macht das ganze schwieriger als es sein müsste

Comment: @Emanuel: Da ist schon ein Unterschied. Bevor sie erwiesen ist, ist von einer Tatsache ja nicht klar, daß sie eine ist. – Man könnte einem Physiker des 19. Jahrhunderts beispielsweise nicht vorwerfen, daß er die Existenz eines Äthers für möglich gehalten hat. Trotzdem war die Nichtexistenz schon damals eine Tatsache.

Comment: Nebenbei bemerkt wird zumindest meiner Wahrnehmung nach unter denjenigen, die sich einigermaßen mit dem Thema auseinandergesetzt haben, das Verneinen Gottes nicht einfach *Atheismus,* sondern *starker Atheismus* genannt. Außerdem findet man in klassischen Lexika gerne mal Dinge, die seit über hundert Jahren unüberprüft von Auflage zu Auflage mitgeschliffen wurden (oder einfach so grober Unfug sind).

Comment: @Chirlu: das geht jetzt dann natürlich in die Philosofie... aber trotzdem: nennt man denn nicht ein Sache erst dann Tatsache, wenn sie erwiesen ist? Vorher ist es keine Tatsache sondern eine Hypothese. Für die Menschen damals war es keine Tatsache, dass Äther nicht existiert. Für uns schon, und das extrapolieren wir jetzt nach hinten und gehen aus guten Gründen davon aus, dass, was heute gilt, auch damals galt

Comment: @Emanuel: Wir können eine Hypothese eine potentielle Tatsache nennen. :-) Ansonsten erinnert es mich gerade an die Frage, ob ein umfallender Baum auch dann Lärm macht, wenn niemand da ist, der ihn hören könnte.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Auf german.SE erlaube ich mir den Hinweis, daß es zwei unterschiedliche Verben _schleifen_ gibt, von denen eines schwach und eines stark konjugiert wird. „Über den Boden ziehen“ ist das mit der schwachen Konjugation. :-)

Comment: @Emanuel: So oder so ist das *erwiesen* zu streichen. Entweder ist es doppelt gemoppelt oder es ist nicht so gemeint, da das Leugnen erwiesener Tatsachen ja nur in den wenigsten Fällen Sinn ergibt und viel häufiger nicht erwiesene Tatsachen geleugnet werden.

Comment: @chirlu: Ich weiß, aber es eignet sich so gut um die Nachlässigkeit und den angerichteten Schaden des Vorgangs (das »Abschleifen der Qualität«) abzuwerten.

Comment: `Hypothese` und `Tatsache` beziehen sich auf völlig verschiedene Aspekte. `Tatsache` bedeutet, dass dasjenige wahr ist. `Hypothese` bedeutet, dass dasjenige (begründet) vermutet wird. Man kann falsche Sachen vermuten, aber man kann auch wahre Sachen (`Tatsachen`) vermuten. Eine Tatsache, z.B. „Ich mag Nudeln.“ kann man vermuten (das tue ich selber zum Beispiel), muss man aber nicht (Angela Merkel vermutet das gerade nicht, weil sie mich gar nicht kennt.)

Comment: Kommentare dienen dazu, Verbesserungsvorschläge zu machen, oder Unklarheiten zu beseitigen. Andere Ansichten sind eine andere Antwort wert. Ansonsten können und sollten wir im [Chat] weiter diskutieren. Denkt an die vielen Leute, die über Google hierher finden. Wer soll denn das alles lesen? Danke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachempfinden ist es auch so, d.h. *leugnen* bedeutet für mich, bewußt die Unwahrheit zu sagen. Die Sprachgemeinschaft im Ganzen sieht es aber weniger eindeutig; hier ein aktueller Beleg aus der Süddeutschen Zeitung:

> Mutmaßlicher „Maskenmann“ leugnet

Würde der Autor in dieser Überschrift *leugnen* im Sinne von „die Unwahrheit sagen“ verstehen, wäre das *mutmaßlich* widersinnig. Somit muß er *leugnen* im Sinne von *abstreiten* verwenden, was in meinen Ohren neutral ist und kein Urteil über die Wahrheit der Aussage enthält.

Auch der Duden gibt als eine mögliche Bedeutung von [leugnen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leugnen) an:

> (etwas, was einem zur Last gelegt oder über einen behauptet wird) für nicht zutreffend oder bestehend erklären

Hier wird diese neutrale Bedeutung also auf Aussagen über sich selbst beschränkt.

---

Insgesamt würde ich empfehlen, um Mißverständnisse zu vermeiden, nur dann *leugnen* zu verwenden, wenn man von der Unwahrheit überzeugt ist; neutrale Alternativen wären *abstreiten* oder *von sich weisen*. Man sollte aber mit der Möglichkeit rechnen, daß andere *leugnen* in einem abgeschwächten Sinn verwenden.

Comment: Verstehe ich nicht. Du stellst fest, dass der offizielle Sprachgebrauch neutral ist, aber um Dein Sprachgefühl nicht zu korrigieren sollen die Leute das Wort so benutzen, wie es Deinem Sprachempfinden passt?

Comment: Wenn viele Leute dieses Sprachgefühl teilen, nützt eine andere Definition im Wörterbuch nicht. Letztlich werden sich die Wörterbücher dem allgemeinen Sprachempfinden anpassen. Alles eine Frage "von der" (sic! :D) Zeit.

Comment: Der Duden gibt übrigens auch die nicht-neutrale Version an: »(etwas Offenkundiges wider besseres Wissen) für unwahr oder nicht vorhanden erklären und nicht gelten lassen« und »(etwas, was als Lehre, Weltanschauung o. Ä. oder allgemein anerkannt ist und vertreten wird) für nicht bestehend erklären«.

Comment: Hä? Leugnen heißt ganz klar etwas abstreiten. Das bedeutet ja nicht, dass man bewusst die Unwahrheit sagt! Wenn ich niemanden umgebracht habe, jemand aber behauptet ich hätte das getan, dann kann ich das leugnen, ohne dabei die Unwahrheit zu sagen. Bezüglich der Bedeutung von *leugnen* gibt's überhaupt keine Möglichkeit, etwas misszuverstehen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Die Frage war nicht völliger Quatsch, aber sie setzt schon falsche Sachen voraus, um davon ausgehend etwas zu erfahren.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Jetzt setzt du auf einmal `völliger Quatsch` und `überflüssig` gleich. Auch das sind grundlegend verschiedene Dinge.

Comment: Kommentare dienen dazu, Verbesserungsvorschläge zu machen, oder Unklarheiten zu beseitigen. Andere Ansichten sind eine andere Antwort wert. Ansonsten können und sollten wir im [Chat] weiter diskutieren. Denkt an die vielen Leute, die über Google hierher finden. Wer soll denn das alles lesen? Danke.

Comment: Könnte sich natürlich auch um eine Form der tendenziösen "Berichterstattung", also Vermischung von Tatsachenbericht und Ansichten des Autors handeln. Etymologisch behaupten scheinbar einige Autoren auch die gleiche Herkunft wie beim Wort "lügen". Aber ich bin kein Sprachwissenschaftler und kann das daher nicht einschätzen, sondern allenfalls wiedergeben.

Answer (score 4):

`Leugnen` bedeutet ganz klar, dass man sagt, dass eine aufgestellte Behauptung falsch sei. Ob die Behauptung wahr/falsch oder erwiesen/unerwiesen oder Lehre/Weltanschauung/Tatsache ist, ist völlig unerheblich.

- Man kann leugnen, einen Mord begangen zu haben. (Entweder wahr oder falsch, möglicherweise schon bewiesen oder nicht, Tatsachenbehauptung.)
- Man kann leugnen, dass Gott existiert. (Wahrheitsgehalt ohne Kommentar, noch nicht bewiesen im Sinn, dass alle diese Behauptung akzeptieren, Weltanschauung)
- Man kann leugnen, dass 1+1=2 ist. (Wahr,bewiesen,Lehre)
- Man kann die Kontinuumshypothese leugnen. (Wahr, wenn man möchte;weder beweisbar noch widerlegbar;Lehre)

Die Konnotation von `leugnen`, dass die referenzierte Behauptung eine erwiesene Tatsache sei, entsteht aus der starken Benutzung dieses Verbs im juristisch-polizeilichen Umfeld und dem latenten Positivismus der Deutschen: Wenn der Polizist/Staatsanwalt behauptet, dass Max Mustermann den Mord begangen habe, dann glaubt das als Außenstehender schon mal gerne. Wenn Max Mustermann das dann leugnet, denkt man sich schon, dass er eine erwiesene Tatsache leugnet. Aber weder muss das eine Tatsache sein (es war ja möglicherweise Maria Mustermann), noch muss es der Polizist/Staatsanwalt bewiesen habe (vielleicht hat er ja nur so ein Bauchgefühl). Der latente Positivismus sorgt aber dafür, dass man dem Polizisten/Staatsanwalt eher glaubt, als dem Beschuldigten.

Comment: Interessante Ansicht zum Thema Entstehung der Konnotation. Danke +1

Answer (score 3):

Die zwei Definitionen von Atheisten ist sowohl ein gutes wie schlechtes Beispiel, weil Gläubige und Atheisten sich über die korrekte Definition uneins sind.

"Leugnen" kann verschiedene Bedeutungen haben, der Ton macht eben die Musik und es kann klaffende Lücken zwischen Denotation and Konnotation geben. "Atheisten: Gottesleugner" ist die oft von Gläubigen bevorzugte Definition, welche unzweifelshaft die willkürliche Nichtakzeptanz einer Tatsache beinhaltet. Aus der Sicht der meisten Atheisten hingegen sind die Gläubigen den Gottesbeweis schuldig, sie leugnen die Existenz Gottes allenfalls im Sinne einer Abstreitung einer unbewiesenen Behauptung und bevorzugen vermutlich die logisch korrekte Defintion von Nicht-Theist. Das Atheisten Beispiel zeigt deutlich, daß "leugnen" mit total oppositionellen Konnotationen verbunden sein kann, abhängig davon auf welcher Seite man steht.

Meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl nach wird "leugnen" meistens im Sinne einer standhaften Abstreitung verwendet; entweder bezichtigt der Sprecher jemand der Lüge, oder ein Kommentator stellt fast, daß eine Beschuldigung strikt abgestritten wurde. Aufgrund dieser Doppeldeutigkeit würde ich wohl nicht "Ich leugne, daß..." sagen, sondern "Ich streite dies ab."

Comment: Danke und +1. Das Beispiel war natürlich gerade deshalb gewählt, weil es den empfundenen kleinen Unterschied herausarbeitet. Aber es ist interessant hier zu sehen wie verschieden die Ansichten sind.

Comment: Dass "unzweifelshaft die willkürliche Nichtakzeptanz einer Tatsache beinhaltet" wird, bezweifle ich, und mit guten Gründen. Gläubige bestreiten oft gar nicht, dass sie nicht wissen, ob es einen Gott gibt, sie haben sich lediglich entschieden sich zu verhalten, als gäbe es einen (oder mehrere, um den Polytheisten nicht Unrecht zu tun). Selbst sehr gläubige Christen betonen gelegentlich, dass der Glaube eine Tugend sei, und etwas "Glaube" zu nennen beinhaltet schon, dass man es nicht für eine erwiesene Tatsache hält. Erwiesene Tatsachen zu glauben bedarf keiner Tugend, das tun wir en passant.

Answer (score 2):

Eine Tat zu leugnen bedeutet nicht, dass man sie begangen hat. Man kann auch Gefühle und Absichten leugnen, und schwerlich lässt sich das Gegenteil nachweisen.

Im Sprachgebrauch Rücksicht auf die zu nehmen, die es falsch verwenden bedeutet, der falschen Verwendung Vorschub zu leisten, und das Wissen um die wahre Form implizit zu leugnen.

Update: Da meine reine Behauptung nicht reicht, hier aus einer Quelle belegt, als da ist: [Deutsches Rechtswörterbuch (DRW)](http://drw-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/drw-cgi/zeige?index=lemmata&term=leugnen)

> ```
> leugnen    
> I verleugnen, ableugnen, abstreiten, bestreiten, nicht anerkennen
> II widerrufen, eine Behauptung zurücknehmen
> III d. Recht verweigern, abschlagen (III 3 b δ) 
> IV verwehren
> V jemanden einen Lügner nennen, ihn der Lüge zeihen
> VI verschweigen, verheimlichen
> VII (e. Ort) verlassen, räumen
> VIII die Eidesleistung (des Beklagten) ablehnen
> ```

bzw.:

> läugnen, verb. verneinen, in abrede stellen.

Quelle: [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GL02330)

Comment: Und diese Antwort ist in keinster Weise hilfreich. Woher denn die Annahme bestreiten wäre nicht neutraler als leugnen in diesem Fall? Zumal der Duden speziell den Fall einer Beschuldigung der eigenen Person als Bedeutung angibt. Aber wie man an meinem Beispiel sieht, geht es nicht um eine solche Beschuldigung.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Du meinst wohl "in keiner Weise". Kein läßt sich nicht steigern - es ist bereits ein Superlativ. Übrigens das gleiche Problem: Da leugnen bereits neutral ist, bezüglich des Wahrheitsgehalts, kann es kein neutraler geben, nicht.

Comment: Ich bin Muttersprachler und behalte es mir vor die Sprache kreativ zu formen. Nach wie vor steht da in Bezug auf "leugnen" nur eine Behauptung aber kein Beleg. Die Gegenteilige Behauptung habe ich ja in meiner Frage aufgestellt. Sie also mit einer Behauptung ohne Belege zu "beantworten" ist mager, nicht magererer \*g\*

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Nun sind Belege da.

Comment: Sorry für die Verspätung, aber ich hab mal das +1 nachgeholt.